# ¿Como puedo agregar un valor a una base datos desde python sqlalchemy?

Tags: mysql, python, flask, sqlalchemy

Buenas tardes amigos de stackoverflow tengo una duda.

Mi duda consiste en que deseo ingresar un valor a un campo ya registrado en una base de datos por medio de sqlalchemy python usando flask como microframework aquí esta mi ejemplo de codigo.

```
@app.route("/activate_email/<string:email>/<string:username>/<string:hashed_password>")
def activate_email(email, username, hashed_password):
    token = User(token=1)
    db.session.add
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template("activate_email.html", name = username, email=email)
```

Osea quiero ingresar un valor 1 al token donde esta el email o usuario registrado. Espero haya sido muy claro de lo contrario no duden en preguntarme.

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema?

Comment: Quiero agregar un valor a uno de los campos de email, y username en una base de datos por medio de sqlalchemy.

Comment: veo que has intentado hacerlo, en esa direccion va mi pregunta, cual es el problema o error que tienes.

Comment: @eyllanesc no hay error solo quiero saber el codigo para agregar un valor a una base de datos buscandolo por medio de el email o usuario en sqlalchemy

Comment: Okay entiendo, que campos tiene tu tabla?

Comment: Es una tabla user solamente y tiene los siguientes campos id, username, email, password, token.

Comment: ¿Quieres actualizar esa fila o quieres crear una nueva?, tu pregunta no es muy clara por eso estoy haciendo varias preguntas.

Comment: @eyllanesc Tranquilo, solo quiero insertar un 1 en el campo token donde ya hay un email registrado ejemplo email = ejemplo@email.com, username = usuario, password = password, token = 0 (token viene por defecto a 0 ), y quiero convertir el token del email ejemplo@email.com en un 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer hacer es filtrar los datos con la ayuda de filter_by que se puede concatenar como muestro a continuación, este retorna un iterable ya que pueden haber varios objetos que cumplan con la condición, entonces actualizamos el campo que se desea, y hacemos un commit.

Ejemplo:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()

#  id, username, email, password, token.
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
    token = Column(Integer)

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///orm_in_detail.sqlite')

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
session = sessionmaker()
session.configure(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

s = session()
user = User(username="username", email="ejemplo@email.com", password="password", token=0)
s.add(user)
s.commit()
# filtro 
results = s.query(User).filter_by(username="username").filter_by(email="ejemplo@email.com")
for result in results:
    # actualizamos el campo
    result.token = 1
    s.commit()
```